# How to parameterize a curve that is the derivative of a Gaussian

Tags: matlab, math, parameters, gaussian, derivative

In the equation of a Gaussian below, I can specify the height (a), width (c) and center (b).

```
f(x) = a*e^[-(x-b)^2 / (2c^2)]
```

The derivative of a Gaussian takes the following form:

[image: gaussian on left, its derivative on right]

**What I would like to do is to come up with an equation where I can specify the height, width, and center of a curve like the gaussian derivative**.

The derivative of the Gaussian equation above is :

```
d = (a*(-x).*exp(-((-x).^2)/(2*c^2)))/(c^2);
```

[image: Derivative of gaussian from image 1]

The 1st order Hermite function takes a similar form.

`d = (((pi)^(-1/4)*exp(-0.5*(x.^2))).*x)*sqrt(2);`

My goal is to have an equation that takes this general form and allows me to specify a height, width, and center.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it isn't about computer programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do two changes in the expression of the derivative of a Gaussian:

- Differentiation preserves changes in height and position. The only problem is that in the expression of the derivative you are missing the parameter `b`. You should **replace `x` by `x-b`**.
- As for changes in width, since the original Gaussian function has area `1`, higher `c` produces more width but also less height. To compensate for that,  **multiply by `c`**, so that height is unafffected by changes in `c`.

So, the parameterized function is

```
d = c*(a*(-x+b).*exp(-((-x+b).^2)/(2*c^2)))/(c^2);
```

**Example:**

```
figure
hold on
grid
x = -20:.1:20;

a = 1; b = 2; c = 3; % initial values
d = c*(a*(-x+b).*exp(-((-x+b).^2)/(2*c^2)))/(c^2);
plot(x, d, 'linewidth', 1) % blue

a = 2; b = 2; c = 3; % change height
d = c*(a*(-x+b).*exp(-((-x+b).^2)/(2*c^2)))/(c^2);
plot(x, d, 'linewidth', 1) % red

a = 1; b = 7; c = 3; % change center
d = c*(a*(-x+b).*exp(-((-x+b).^2)/(2*c^2)))/(c^2);
plot(x, d, 'linewidth', 1) % yellow

a = 1; b = 2; c = 5; % change width
d = c*(a*(-x+b).*exp(-((-x+b).^2)/(2*c^2)))/(c^2);
plot(x, d, 'linewidth', 1) % purple
```

[image]

Comment: Great information, Luis.  Thank you.  I made one small adjustment so that I can specify the peak of the function. By replacing c*() at the beginning of your equation with (c*exp(.5))*(), the parameter (a) will specify the peak/trough of the function.  If there is a more elegant way to do this I'd be interesting but this seems to work.  Thank you once again. 

    d = (c*exp(.5))*(a*(-x+b).*exp(-((-x+b).^2)/(2*c^2)))/(c^2);

Comment: @adamdanz Good idea, that way `c` directly specifies the actual height. Glad I could help!